# PHP rating system

Tags: php

I have a table (review) which stores the values (1-5) for ratings. I will use the sum of these ratings for the overall score.

I have 5 stars on the page which will show on or off depending on the overall value.

I have the overall score by counting the total value of all the ratings divided by the number of reviews in the table. This give a value below 5 every time...great.

However I now have a problem where the value could either be 1.5 or 1.75 for instance. If the value is 1.5 I will show 1 and a half stars on and 3 and a half stars off. How should I determine if the value is 1.75 to show only the 1.5 value star.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Perhaps you could post the relevant code?

Comment: Rating systems that have a scale (eg: 1-5, 1-10) aren't very good to determine rating. Everyone has different standards, so all this does is complicate things without adding much (if any) value. Take Youtube for example, they used to have a stars system now it's just like or dislike. See:  [UX: Rate vs Like/Dislike](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/4200/rate-vs-like-dislike)

Comment: Client requirement to have a star rating system unfortunately. Basically I just want to only ever have the result a full number or a .5 variable.

Comment: A true rating system should also consider standard deviation, but we would need to know your complete data set to get into that.

Answer (score 1):

That should be a simple math problem, since your resolution is 1/2, multiply by two, round it, then divide by 2:

```
round(x * 2) / 2

round((1.75) * 2) / 2 = 2
round((1.65) * 2) / 2 = 1.5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$tests = array(-1, 0, 0.25, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 1.75, 3, 4.22, 6);

foreach($tests as $test)
  echo "Initial rate = ".$test.", adjusted rate = ".adjustRate($test)."\n";

function adjustRate($val)
{
  if ($val < 0)
    return 0;

  if ($val > 5)
    return 5;

  return floor($val * 2) / 2;
}
```

Gives for example:

```
Initial rate = 1.75, adjusted rate = 1.5
```